# Adding or Removing an Item in a Laravel Form

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have form which will create a delivery-request.  Basically on that form, the user needs to add / remove an item and their quantity.

This is how I structured my table:

**items**

- id
- item_name

**delivery-request**

- id
- delivery_request_number
- requested_by

**delivery-request_item**

- id
- delivery_request_id
- item_id
- item_quantity

Let's say for example, a user creates a delivery request.
And adds 3 pcs of X-printer, 2 pcs of Y-ink.

Since cicking on submit  on the *'add item'* button will reload the or redirect the user's browser. How can I Add/Remove said item, and then when saving I would assume having something like:

**items**

- id = 1
- item_name = X-printer
- id = 2
- item_name = Y-ink

**delivery-request**

- id = 001
- delivery_request_number = 0001
- requested_by = John Doe

**delivery-request_item**

- id = 1
- delivery_request_id = 0001
- item_id = 1
- item_quantity = 3
- id = 2
- delivery_request_id = 0001
- item_id = 2
- item_quantity = 2

I am clueless as how to execute that.

```
//create.blade.php
{{Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','route'=>'delivery-requests.store'))}}  
  {{Form::text('Requested by', Auth::user()->email, array('disabled'=>'true'))}}

  <div>
    {{Form::label('Shows Items from table')}}   
    {{Form::select('items', $items)}}

    {{Form::label('Quantity')}}
    {{Form::text('item_quantity')}}

    {{Form::submit('add item',array('name'=>'addItem'))}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
        <theader>
            <tr>
                <td>ITEM NAME</td>
                <td>QUANTITY</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </theader>
        <tbody>
                <!-- loop through the items -->
                <td> {{-- Item name --}}</td>
                <td> {{-- Quantity--}}</td>
                <td> {{Form::submit('remove item', array('name' => 'removeItem'))}} </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  {{Form::submit('submit', array('name' => 'submit'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

---

Now I still haven't completed my code for **DeliveryRequestsController** since I am unsure how to proceed.

```
// DeliveryRequestsController
public function store()
{
    if(Input::has('addItem'))
    {
        // see if itme is already added,
        // add the item and quantity

        return Redirect::to('delivery-requests/create');
    }
    elseif(Input::has('removeItem'))
    {
        // remove the item and quantity

        return Redirect::to('delivery-requests/create');
    }
    elseif(Input::has('submit'))
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $delivery_request = new DeliveryRequest;
        $delivery_request-> = Input::get('requested_by');
        $delivery_request->save()

        // get all items and quantities, save it

        return Redirect::to('delivery-requests');
    }
    else
    {
        return 'something went wrong';
    }
    return Redirect::route('delivery-requests.index');
}
```

---

**Edit**

As you can see from the screenshot below, I still need to redirect to the same page and also display what items where added.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You do have some syntax errors, but this should work for you assuming you are populating your select with values that match the id of the items..

```
$delivery_request = new DeliveryRequest();
$delivery_request->requested_by = Input::get('requested_by');
$delivery_request->save();

$delivery_request->items()->attach(Input::get('items'), array('quantity' => Input::get('item_quantity')));
```

If I may make one suggestion though, I'd rename `DeliveryRequest` to `Cart` simply because it makes a lot more sense logically.  Then you could have `Delivery` which can be made up by many `Cart` items.

Comment: Oh that should be easy.  I'm assuming you have an `index()` function which brings up this page in the first place, just return that...  `return $this->index();`.  As long as the items have been added and your index function is apparently querying for added items, should work great.

Comment: Okay, I'm still trying wrap my head around what you're saying, as of now the `index()`, only displays the something like `DeliveryRequest::all()` , anyway the idea is just to display all created records.

Comment: You already have a function which is responsible for grabbing all the delivery requests you made, it looks like by user and then returning the appropriate view, probably `create.blade.php`.  The idea is that whenever you are finished adding new DeliveryRequests, you return that function, which will again query for all the delivery requests and return the view.

Comment: I think I might have misread your first comment, Yes I have an `index()` which brings up all the DeliveryRequests created, but the page that has the form, is `create()`.

Let me just clarify somethings on the form the bottom part there "Requested Items" does not show the index(), instead it just displays all items added so far with the current delivery request.

I'm sorry if this has become somewhat confusing, let me know if I just misunderstood your answer and comments.

Comment: Yeah I'm a little confused now about what your question is.  Is the `return Redirect::to('delivery-requests');` not working for you?  It should be refreshing the page as long as that route is the same route you are using to open the page with the form on it.

Comment: Well the`return Redirect::to('delivery-requests');` does refresh the page,  but on what I did is `return Redirect::to('delivery-request')->with('added_item',$added_item);` and on the create.bade.php I have a section which has `@if(isset($added_item))` unfortunately after getting redirected the page still considers it 'unset'. Thank you for your response, this comment thread has gotten long. If anything comes up might as well post a new question.

Comment: Oh okay, I think you might be making this harder than it needs to be.  If you redirect back to that route, you shouldn't need to do anything extra as it will run through the entire process of building that page again just like it is now.  As long as the extra data has been inserted into your tables in the `store()` method, you shouldn't have to worry about anything else.  You won't need to check for `$added_item` in your template and you don't need to append any data on your request with `->with('added_item',$added_item)`